# Analysis services 2008 : decimal numbers truncate in cube olap

Tags: ssas, olap

I'm working on olap cube (with analysis services 2008). In my database  I have a column (datatype =NUMBERS(40,30) ). In this column there's values with 10 numbers after the coma example : 125.256987452122 or 159.2365894123658

In my cube olap,  that column is match to a measure. When I look the values in the cube,
I don't have the same value with the database. example :  125.256987452122  ==> in cube 125.2569 or  159.2365894123658 ==> in cube 159.2365

Even when I set the measure property FORMATSTRING = ''### ### ### ### ##0.0000000000;-### ### ### ### ##0.0000000000''  I get this result 25.256987452122  ==> in cube 125.2569000000
or  159.2365894123658 ==> in cube 159.2365000000.

The mesure datatype is Double . I change it to currency but I have the same problem.

Did someone know how to get the same  result as  in the data base , in my cube olap  : 
 159.2365894123658 ==> in cube 159.2365894123658   ???

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimal solution perhaps, but consider storing the data in the underlying database as float, or use a view to load your fact table that converts it to float. SSAS cube will only show 4 digits unless you use Float.

You can verify this by exploring the data with your current datatype in the DSV, it should show all decimals, yet SSAS will only show 4 digits.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But even when I store the data in the underlying database as float,I just have 4 digits in the cube .  the underlying database is a oracle database. I change datatype NUMBER(40,10) to flaot. but have the same problem. the datatype I use for the measure is DOUBLE.

Comment: Use float for the datatype of the measure, not double.

Comment: There's no datatype Float for the measure in the cube olap. There's just Double and Currency